# Render spaces before line begins

Tags: bibliographies

I have manually created references in my latex project. It looks like :

[image]

I want to align the text so that it appears like:

[image]

I tried using hfill before lines but its not working. Pleas help.

Comment: You are looking for either hanging paragraphs or adjustment of margins in lists.  However, you need to show us what your coding is so far.  Also please explain why you are not using a `bibliography` environment.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sir, I said I wrote the Refernces myself. I wrote the numbers I pasted the references. This is a text problem not biblatex problem.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I could not use it due to some reasons, I tried using it got something and switched to writing manually as a quick fix. And now I urgently need to get it working, plz help.

Comment: @Novak007: Agreed, I read too fast. But your text problem occurs because your not using `biblatex` etc

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes I know,  next time I am writing I will surely use biblatex, now is there now way in latex my problem could be solved ?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Could this be fixed in latex ? What should I do now that I am constrained in using this only ?

Comment: Without knowing *how* you created the list of references we can only guess. Please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows your bibliography list, but please make sure the example is truly minimal.

Comment: Almost all of your question haven't got an answer so far, answering them would involve pure guesswork. Please give some feedback on the proposed solution in comments, or add the needed information.

Answer (score 3):

A quick manual solution can use `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` to indent the lines after the first line of a paragraph = bibliography entry:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\BibItemWidth}
\newcommand*{\BibITem}{}% ensure, \BibItem is undefined
\def\BibItem[#1]{%
  \par
  \hangindent=\BibItemWidth
  \hangafter=1 %
  \noindent
  \hbox to \BibItemWidth{\hfil[#1] }\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{6}% omitting the other six sections
\section{References}

\settowidth{\BibItemWidth}{[99] }% use widest number here

\BibItem[1] Paasch, Christoph, and Oliver Bonav\dots\\
  57.4 (2014): 51--57.

\BibItem[2] Teixeira, Renata, \dots\\
  ACM SIGMETRICS Performance \dots

\BibItem[10] C. Raiciu, C. Paasch, S. Barre, A. Ford, \dots\\
  F. Duchene, O. Bonaventure, and \dots

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]